# Search models defined with "through"

Tags: django, models, m2m

I have the following models (details are omitted):

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=200, blank=False)    

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=200, blank=False)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, blank=False, through='Book_Author')

class Book_Author(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

I want to get all books whose title contains given query and whose author's name contains the same query.

Now I am doing the following:

To get all books whose title contains the word I use this code:

```
for word in words:          
        books = books.filter(Q(title__icontains=word)
```

To get all books whose author's name contains the word I use this code:

```
for word in words:        
        authors = authors.filter(Q(name__icontains=word))        
        for author in authors:      
          for book_author in author.book_author_set.all():
             book = Book.objects.get(id=book_author.book_id)
             results.append(book)
```

Is there any way to improve the second part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easy way:

```
for word in words:          
    books = books.filter(Q(title__icontains=word) )
    books = books.filter(Q(author__name__icontains=word) )

my_books = books.distinct()
```

*** EDITED ***

If you are looking for books where title contains words OR author contains words, then the query is:

```
q_books = None
q_authors = None
for word in words:          
    q_aux = Q(title__icontains=word)
    q_books = (q_books & q_aux ) if bool( q_books) else q_aux
    q_aux = Q(author__name__icontains=word)
    q_authors = (q_authors & q_aux ) if bool( q_authors) else q_aux

my_books = Book.objects.filter( q_books | q_authors ).distinct()
```

Any comment for more code readability are wellcome.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. Could you explain how the line with "if" works?

Comment: This is a conditional expressions. Learn more about it in [PER 308](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions)